# How to open dialog by using jquery 1.9.1 in zendfox framework?

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery-ui-dialog

How to open dialog by using jquery 1.9.1 in zendfox framework? 
if we have a problem in dialog open is c.browser undefined by using jquery 1.9.1,then how can handle this problem.....pls help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

link related files and 
use `$(selector).dialog()` to call dialog.
see [Jquery Dialog](https://jqueryui.com/dialog/)